# IF THEN in mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I need to find the correct syntax for this php mysql query and despite searching and trial and error, I've drawn a blank.

I have a table of stockists -'Stockists' and I need to pull the data from each row depending on the presence of state1, state2 or both.If only state1 is present then pull that record,if they're both present then I need the record based on state2.

```
SELECT * FROM `Stockists` WHERE state1 = 'vic' AND state2 IS NULL
IF state2 IS NOT NULL
THEN
SELECT * FROM `Stockists` WHERE state2 = 'vic'
```

I've searched and played with quite a few different examples but nothing seems to work.Any advice or leads would be most appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You've done a grave mistake there - you have value `vic` and you are swapping the column you're searching for that value. In SQL, we do things the other way around - our columns are constant, and our values change. Also, the IF is done in the SELECT part, not after WHERE. Technically, even if you get around the issue of somehow coming up with a solution, your design is 100% unmistakably wrong. In order to do things the way we want, we use normalization which lets us query the data in various ways (and it always works). Your design is not normalized.

Comment: that's a little harsh, you don't know what situation caused the data to be arranged such; it may be an inherited database for all we know.

Comment: @pala_ - I'm not discussing *what* caused the design to be such, I'm only highlighting the issues caused by such approach. When people use the tools the wrong way, bad things happen - just like here. Then a huge hack is required to make it work as intended, when only thing that was supposed to be done is a simple and proper data-model construct.

Comment: I don't understand is state1 an state2 columns of a table?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback NB but @pala is indeed correct.  The database comes directly from MYOB software.  Thanks for taking the time to tell me how wrong I'm doing things though.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from stockists
    where (state2 = 'vic') or (state1 = 'vic' and state2 is null);
```

Try this out. Gets all stockists with state2 set to vic, and also all stockists with state1 set to vic, where state2 is not set.  Here's a demo to try out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15a08/1

It won't retrieve records where state1 = 'vic' and state2 = 'someotherstate'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Stockists WHERE (state2 IS NULL and state1 = 'vic') 
  OR (state2  = 'vic')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it's answer on your question, but here you can understand how if statment works in mysql.

```
SELECT
    IF(state1 = 'vic', 'yes', 'no') as 'match fist condition',
    IF(state2 = 'vic', 'yes', 'no') as 'match second condition',
    IF(state1 = 'vic' and state2 = 'vic', 'yes', 'no') as 'match both conditions'
FROM stockists
WHERE state1 = 'vic' or state2 = 'vic'
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    `Stockists` 
WHERE 
    IF(state1 = 'vic', state1 = 'vic' , (state1 = 'vic' OR state2 ='vic'))
```

try this and let me know.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it doesn't answer the question either.